# How to change the column width/ratio in Flexible Column Layout?

Tags: sapui5

The predefined ratios of `sap.f.LayoutType` for two columns in Flexible Column Layout are

- 67/33/- `TwoColumnsBeginExpanded`
- 33/67/- `TwoColumnsMidExpanded`

Is there a way to change the ratio/width of the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to have a 50%/50% ratio, but it seems not possible according to [Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3b9f760da5b64adf8db7f95247879086)

> Although the FlexibleColumnLayout can display 2 or 3 pages at one
>   time, they can never have equal width (50%/50% or 33%/33%/33%). One of
>   the pages is always larger (expanded) or even takes up the full width
>   of the control (fullscreen). This is intentional because users should
>   have a clear indication of what to focus their attention on at any
>   given moment, for example, a list of items, one particular item, one
>   item’s details.

Now I'm using sap.ui.layout.ResponsiveSplitter instead.

Comment: If you were trying to achive 50/50, then [`sap.ui.layout.DynamicSideContent`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.ui.layout.DynamicSideContent/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.DynamicSideContentEqualSplit) is also an option.